# There is no procedure with the name `apoc.export.cypher.all` registered for this database instance

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to export my database to Cypher using help from [this](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/cypher/#export-cypher-neo4j-browser) guide. When I run the following query, it responds with an error.

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.all("all-plain.cypher", {
format: "plain",
useOptimizations: {type: "UNWIND_BATCH", unwindBatchSize: 20}
})
YIELD file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize
RETURN file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize;
```

I copied the query and pasted it directly to the console. Here is my error:

> There is no procedure with the name `apoc.export.cypher.all` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

My instance is running on Docker container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the APOC before be able to use them.

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/